# Where are the settings for 'iwconfig' stored?

Tags: networking, ifconfig

I'm going to be fiddling around with my wireless card's settings by using `iwconfig`. Before doing this, I would like to back up my current settings in case anything goes horribly wrong.

Where are the config options for `iwconfig` stored so I can back them up, and restore them when needed?

Answer (score 2):

If you use Network Manager settings are in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`.

In that folder you have all connection, in My case:

```
Auto router03  Auto router02
Auto router04  Auto dlink_DWR-512  
Wired connection 1
```

After Auto is name of SSID

example

```
zzz@zzz ~ $ sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Auto\ dlink_DWR-512 
[connection]
id=Auto dlink_DWR-512
uuid=6c358756-06b1-4c5b-9eca-a6c8d52a5456
type=802-11-wireless

[802-11-wireless]
ssid=dlink_DWR-512
mode=infrastructure
mac-address=00:21:5C:8A:60:AB

[ipv6]
method=auto

[ipv4]
method=auto
```